# Is the Clip class appropriate for 'heavy use'?

Tags: java, audio, clip

I'm working on a program that plays a series of `Clip`s (`clip.start()`), on average one each second.

Meaning a clip is started, and a second later it is stopped and another clip is started, and so on for about 10 clips.

The outcome isn't 'fluid', some clips don't even start or aren't heard.

My question: is the Clip class appropriate for this kind of thing? Or are clips not supposed to handle being stopped and started very frequently?

If Clip isn't appropriate, is there an alternative class or library you can suggest for this purpose? Or maybe some guidelines on how to work with Clips so what I described would work fluidly? (Maybe regarding threading or something).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much experience with audio in Java, but the experience I've had with Clips is poor. I've found that for some reason it takes up to half a second to restart a clip which is not acceptable (found some old bugs that were apparently fixed relating to this issue, but perhaps it was a new bug at the time I was looking into it). A SourceDataLine with a buffer to hold your entire sound has worked better for me.

However, I would suggest [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound), it's a simple abstraction that works.

Here's the example from their page:

```
    //initialize TinySound
    TinySound.init();
    //load a sound and music
    //note: you can also load with Files, URLs and InputStreams
    Music song = TinySound.loadMusic("song.wav");
    Sound coin = TinySound.loadSound("coin.wav");
    //start playing the music on loop
    song.play(true);
    //play the sound a few times in a loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        coin.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    //be sure to shutdown TinySound when done
    TinySound.shutdown();
```